# libpcap: 64bit machine has no compatible 32-bit libpcap library

Tags: c, linux, tcpdump

I want to compile a `.c` file to 32-bit executable using `gcc` option `-m32` with libpcap
the machine is linux 64bit fedora 16

however, I get the following error

```
[root@fdf source]# gcc -m32 -o test_tcp test_tcp.c -lpcap
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libpcap.so when searching for -lpcap
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcap
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I installed

```
 yum install libpcap.i686
```

and then try to compile, but still  get errors:

```
root@ddh-4.0# gcc -m32 -o test_tcp test_tcp.c -lpcap
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libpcap.so when searching for -lpcap
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcap
```

Comment: Install the 32-bit library? On most modern systems it's possible to have both 64-bit and 32-bit variants installed at the same time. Don't know how it works on Fedora 16, or what the packages are named.

Comment: I'm just wondering why 64-bit libpcap library doesn't include 32-bit variant?

Comment: The 32bit version library is not included by default. You can install it by "yum install libpcap.i686".

Comment: will it conflict with the 64-bit version?

Comment: I installed libpcap.i686, but still get errors: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcap`

Comment: ld doesn't find your 32bits libpcap. You could include the install directory of your 32bit libpcap in the environnement variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to solve this

Comment: how to include the install directory of your 32bit libpcap in the environnement variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH? and how to find the install directory? thanks!

Comment: I use `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but got nothing, it is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the development package in addition to the runtime library. So do

yum install libpcap-devel.i686

Comment: if a machine are with tcpdump, that machine doesn't necessarily have libpcap-devel, then can my program run on that machine? thanks!

Comment: Yes, the -devel packages are for development, i.e. compiling and linking, and isn't needed at runtime.